# Xcode Localizable String Problem - everything is bold

Tags: swift, xcode, uilabel

I want to translate my app to different languages with localizable strings and it worked so far.

My problem is I have very long texts in my app and in the translated version everything of the UILabel text is bold. But I only need some parts to be bold.
I could make for every language a new storyboard with a new main document, but I am afraid my app will get slow with this solution.

Is there an easy solution where I can edit the translated version? I am using Xcode 14.

I don't even know what to try.

Comment: Please edit your question and show clear examples of your issue. Show relevant code and/or data (as text).

Comment: How do you use translations? With `NSLocalizedString`? If yes, you could use tags, custom, markdown, html etc, and init the `NSAttributedString` with that localization and add the desired effect wherever it's needed.

Comment: Thank you so much Larme!! That helped me a lot i did it with localized strings! Thank you